# Is It wrong to annotate frame from one video for creating a custom dataset for object detection?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, annotations, object-detection, yolo

I have a project to create a custom dataset for one specific CCTV camera on helsinki port.
I was trying to annotate the frames of saved video from this camera but the result on training is not accurate and there is lots of wrong annotation in the object detection.
i saw some videos on youtube and they were advicing to not use back to back frames of video for annotation. but there is no rule or instruction for this.

I annotate more than 2000 frame of one video from this camera. also i used YOLO-NAS for training the data. but the result was not good enough.